# Fijar un solo nivel de una variable al correr regresiones lineales en R

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente sencillo modelo lineal en R:

```
xmdl <- lm(Voto ~ Edad + Educacion,
           data = datostotales)
summary(xmdl)
```

Imaginemos que "Edad" es una variable con valores que oscilan de 20 a 100 (en pasos discretos de 1), y que "Educación" es un factor que tiene dos niveles "Alta" y "Baja".

Me gustaría saber cómo correr la regresión lineal fijando un solo nivel de cada variable. Por ejemplo:

¿Cómo hago la regresión fijando que la variable "Edad" sea igual a 25?
¿Cómo hago la regresión fijando que la variable "Educación" sea "Alta"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo posible trata de agregar un ejemplo válido de los datos, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma: `dput(datostotales)`. Como no tengo estos datos voy a generar un ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
datostotales <- data.frame(Edad=sample(x=c(18:90), size=1000, replace = TRUE),
                           Educacion=sample(x=c("Alta", "Baja"), size=1000, replace = TRUE),
                           Voto=sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4), size=1000, replace = TRUE),
                           stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Ahora bien, si queremos aplicar la regresión únicamente sobre aquellas filas en las que `Edad == 25` podemos hacer esto:

```
xmdl <- lm(Voto ~ Edad + Educacion, data = datostotales[datostotales$Edad==25,])
```

En el caso de educación que tienes dos niveles `Alta` y `Baja` si solo fijamos un nivel además de tener poco sentido incorporar el dato a la formula, al ser un `Factor` la regresión te daría un error. De todas formas eventualmente podrías resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```
xmdl <- lm(Voto ~ Edad + as.numeric(Educacion), data = datostotales[datostotales$Educacion == "Alta",])
```

Nota: Por las dudas lo comento, `Votos` pareciera ser una variable categórica, en cuyo caso la regresión lineal no parece ser el mejor modelo si lo que terminas buscando es hacer una predicción.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Respuesta muy completa. En cuanto a tus dudas sobre la variable "Voto", no era más que un ejemplo para contextualizar la pregunta. Este modelo lineal es una simplificación extrema de una csv mucho más complejo. Por lo que no hay tal variable "voto". En mi modelo real la variable dependiente es continua. Por otra parte, data.frame en mi modelo real es un csv file enorme, por eso no los aporté en el ejemplo. Muchas gracias de nuevo @Patricio Moracho

Comment: ¿y si en mi modelo de regresión tuviera 3 variables independientes en lugar de dos? Por ejemplo, xmdl <- lm(Voto ~ Edad + Educacion + Dinero, data = datostotales). ¿Cómo podría hacer para fijar dos niveles a la vez, por ejemplo, siguiendo los casos anteriores, fijar Edad en 25, y Educación en "Alta", pero a la vez?

Comment: La forma es la misma, lo que haríamos es aplicar la regresión a un dataframe "filtrado" por más de un criterio. La forma básica de filtrar es así `df[df$Edad == 25 & df$Educacion=="Alta", ]`. Puedes eventualmente asignar también los resultados del filtro a un nuevo `dataframe` y trabajar directamente con este último para que te sea más cómodo.